# How to check if values at even and odd positions (within an array) are the same?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

Let say I've an array with a size between 700.000 and 800.000, and I need to iterate it to do some fancy task.

For "same even and odd positions" I mean:

```
[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3] // even and odd are the same

[0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3] // even and odd are not the same (arr[0] and arr[1] are differents)

[0,0,1,1,2,2,3] // even and odd are not the same (last value missing)
```

If values at even and odd position are the same, I need to apply this function to each value:

```
transition_left_right << i*@maxS
```

If even and odd are different, I have to apply this function to each even value:

```
transition_left << i*@maxE
```

and this to each odd value:

```
transition_right << i*@maxO
```

What's the fastest way to do it? (without iterate the huge array many times). Best would be 1 iteration...

Comment: What do you mean by "even and odd values"? Do you mean `arr[0]` equals `arr[1]`, `arr[2]` equals `arr[3]`, and so on, or do you mean something else? Please edit your question to include sample input and the expected output.

Comment: @Jordan: edited. Hope the question is more clear. Yes I meant what you had write

Comment: Your question is still a bit unclear. Which of these do you mean? A. If *any* even-odd pair is unequal, apply the second function to *all* even values and the third function to *all* odd values, and otherwise apply the first function to *all* values; or B. For all even-odd pairs, if a given even-odd pair is unequal, apply the second function to that even value only and the third function to that odd value only, and otherwise apply the first function to that even value and odd value only?

Comment: If just one pair is different, apply to both different function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sschmeck's answer shows, `Enumerable#each_slice` is the way to go. I'm assuming `transition_left_right`, `transition_left`, `transition_right`, `@maxS`, `@maxO`, and `@maxE` are variables that already exist, and `i` is the even or odd value from the array.

If that's the case, then I think you want this:

```
result = arr.each_slice(2) do |left, right|
  if left == right
    transition_left_right << left * @maxS
    transition_left_right << right * @maxS
  else
    transition_left << left * @maxE
    transition_right << right * @maxO unless right.nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: No. During iteration `@maxS`, `@maxO`, and `@maxE` got different values due to the current step.

Comment: Well, it should be pretty evident how to add those calculations to the code above.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
# odd/even always the same?
[1,1,2,2,3].each_slice(2).all? { |a,b| a == b }
#=> false

# hope I got your explaination right
@maxO, @maxE = 2, 3
[1,1,2,2,3].each_slice(2).flat_map do |odd,even|
  odd == even ? [odd,even] : [odd*@maxO, even && even*@maxE]
end.compact
#=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 6]
```